# URL decoding inside AWK

Tags: awk, urldecode

One of the columns in my file is url encoded, I have to decode that column and need to perform some operations based on values inside the column. Is there any way I can decode that column in awk?

Comment: this question is NOT a duplicate of the one mentioned, the title of which is wrong.

Comment: This is not a duplicate.  This question's answer solved a problem for me that the other one did not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to adapt it depending your file format, but the basic principle is here (tested with GNU Awk 3.1.7):

```
sh$ echo 'Hello%2C%20world%20%21' | awk '
     {
         for (i = 0x20; i < 0x40; ++i) {
             repl = sprintf("%c", i);
             if ((repl == "&") || (repl == "\\"))
                 repl = "\\" repl;
             gsub(sprintf("%%%02X", i), repl);
             gsub(sprintf("%%%02x", i), repl);
         }
         print
     }
 '
Hello, world !
```

---

If you have `gawk`, you can wrap that in a function (credit to [*brendanh* in a comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17002841/url-decoding-inside-awk/17002940#comment42444424_17002940)):

```
function urlDecode(url) {
    for (i = 0x20; i < 0x40; ++i) {
        repl = sprintf("%c", i);
        if ((repl == "&") || (repl == "\\")) {
            repl = "\\" repl;
        }
        url = gensub(sprintf("%%%02X", i), repl, "g", url);
        url = gensub(sprintf("%%%02x", i), repl, "g", url);
    }
    return url;
}
```

Comment: My string is like this:
'http%3a%2f%2fwww.gazelle.com%2fiphone%2fiphone-3g'
the above operation couldn't decode this string..:(

Comment: Obviously, I used the format '%02X' which match URL encoded with percent-sign in _uppercase_ like `http%3A%2F...` I modified the sample code to convert lower-case percent-encoding too. Now it should works with both ... at least up to `%40` (upper limit of the for loop). You might have to adjust that...

Comment: My String is like this:

1370474740&http%3a%2f%2fwww.xxxx.com%2fiphone%2fiphone-3g&et%3da%26ago%3d212%26ao%3d219%26px%3d73%26av1%3d2%26av2%3dOrganicSearch&13456

when i use awk like this:
awk 'BEGIN {FS = "&"}  {for (i = 0x20; i < 0x40; ++i) gsub(sprintf("%%%02x", i), sprintf("%c", i));print $1,$2,$3}'

'%26' which is '&' is not getting converted, why?

Comment: This one was tough! I wasn't remembering that `&` and `\ ` have special meaning in the replacement string for `gsub`. It is fixed in the answer (I hope)

Comment: This worked, but the decoded '&'s were are also considered as FS.

Comment: FWIW a slightly modified gawk-only version of the answer, as a function:
```
function urlDecode(url) {
   for (i = 0x20; i < 0x40; ++i) {
     repl = sprintf("%c", i);
     if ((repl == "&") || (repl == "\\")) {
        repl = "\\" repl;
     }
     url = gensub(sprintf("%%%02X", i), repl, "g", url);
     url = gensub(sprintf("%%%02x", i), repl, "g", url);
   }
   return url;
}
```

Comment: @brendanh I took the liberty to add your function in my answer. If you do not agree with that, please feel free to revert that edit.

Comment: While this function works, it's quite slow, i found a much much faster one here https://github.com/Knorkebrot/werc/blob/master/bin/contrib/urldecode.awk